# How can I have a rounded rectangle shape in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have a "somewhat" big rounded cornered rectangle, how can I achieve that?

I've tried using BoxDecoration and things like that and none of them worked.

Comment: Can you show the output screenshot, how you want it to be?

Comment: [Like this :)](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/344269447550468096/612702771228966923/unknown.png) as I said I've already managed to achieved that :)

Comment: @TheOnlyArtz this site is a collaborative effort and editing is a normal part of that process. The community is trying to help you create better contributions to our question collection. If that’s not something you are okay with then perhaps this isn’t the site for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have that, all you need to do is increase radius, width and height value.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext build) {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 360.0,
      height: 250.0,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(36.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(color: Colors.black12, offset: Offset(3.0, 6.0), blurRadius: 10.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Output:**

[image]